# A complex polynomial is determined by its zeros and ones.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two non-constant complex polynomials (in one variable).
Assume that
$$
\{z:\ P(z)=0\} = \{z:\ Q(z)=0\} \text{ and } \{z:\ P(z)=1\} = \{z:\ Q(z)=1\}
$$

> Then show that $P=Q$.

I tried this: Define a polynomial $R=P-Q$. Now the roots of $R$ include the zeros as well as the ones of $P$ (and Q). If I could show that the set of zeros and ones of $P$ together form a set of degree greater than $P$ then we will be done since then $R$ would be the zero polynomial. But I am not even sure if that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original idea works.

I will prove the following

> Lemma: Let $P$ be a non-constant complex polynomial of degree $d$. Let $n$ and $m$ be the number of different zeros of $P$ and $P-1$, respectively. Then we have $n+m\geq d+1$.

The original question follows from the lemma by considering $P-Q$.

Proof of Lemma: Write $P=c\prod_{i=1}^n(x-z_i)^{r_i}$ and $P-1=c\prod_{j=1}^m(x-w_j)^{s_j}$. We have $$\frac{P'}P=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r_i}{x-z_i}$$ and similarly $$\frac{P'}{P-1}=\frac{(P-1)'}{P-1}=\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{s_j}{x-w_j}.$$

Taking the difference, we get:
$$\frac{P'}{P(P-1)}=\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{s_j}{x-w_j}-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r_i}{x-z_i}.$$

Multiplying both sides by $F=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(x-z_i)\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^m(x-w_j)\right)$, we see that the right hand side becomes a polynomial $G$. Therefore we have $FP'= P(P-1)G$, which has degree at least $2d$. Since $P'$ has degree $d-1$, it follows that $n+m=\deg F\geq d+1$.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the zeros of $P$ and $Q$ are the same means that $P$ and $Q$ are both of the form $(x-z_1)^{p_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-z_n)^{p_n}$, where $p_i$'s for $P$ can be different from the $p_i$'s for $Q$.

The proof that the powers must be equal is done by induction.  The result is clearly true when the number of factors is $1$.  So fix $P(z)$, let $n$ be the smallest possible number of factors in any polynomial sharing its roots and 1's with $P(z)$, and let $Q(z)$ be a polynomial with that number of factors.  If $P(z)\neq Q(z)$, then we can multiply and divide $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ in a way that would result in a polynomial with a smaller number of factors, which would be a contradiction.

To answer your comment, an example for the number of factors being $2$ is:

If $P(x)=(x-z_1)^{p_1}(x-z_2)^{p_2}$ and $Q(x)=(x-z_1)^{q_1}(x-z_2)^{q_2}$, then WLOG assume $p_1\neq q_1$.  Then $P(x)^{q_1}\neq Q(x)^{p_1}$.  And dividing them, we see that $R(x)$ := $P(x)^{q_1}/Q(x)^{p_1}$ has the same set of $1$'s as $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$.  On the other hand, $R(x)=(x-z_2)^{q_1p_2-p_1q_2}$ (or 1/R(x) if that exponent is negative) is a polynomial consisting of just $1$ factor, contradicting the assumption that $Q(x)$ was the polynomial with the smallest number of factors that had the same roots as $P(x)$.

Comment: After we manipulate at the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ in the "multiply and divide" step, it is not clear that the induction hypothesis is still applicable.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: From what I can tell, your idea is to consider the polynomials $P(z)/(z-z_1)$ and $Q(z)/(z-z_1)$. These two polynomials share their zeros, but not necessarily their ones. So one can apply induction to conclude that these two polynomials are the same. Of course, if your idea is something else then perhaps you could elaborate on your answer and ignore my cooment.

Comment: No, my idea is something entirely different.  But I better update the post, since it won't fit in the comment.

Comment: OK, done.  Take a look now.  I've seen this solution in Complex Analysis, so that's how I know.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I will accept in some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102330/discussion-between-alex-and-caffeinemachine).

Comment: I didn't see how this argument works, especially the example with two factors. Why does $R(x)$ have the same set of $1$'s as $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$? And why does $R(x)$ share the same roots with $P(x)$? It definitely misses the root $z_1$. Therefore I gave my own answer below.